# Calculating formulas automatically

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am using Microsoft Excel 2010.

Values are downloaded from a database to Excel. I have formulas written in Excel. My formulas would be using the values downloaded to Excel and showing the value of formula in one cell.

The value is not showing automatically and I need to press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to see the value (calculated using formula of that cell).

Is there a way to avoid pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>?

Downloading the values and writing in Excel through Java, Hibernate. It is not a VBA application.

Comment: Go to the Formulas tab, click on 'Calculations Options' and opt for 'Automatic'?

Comment: go to VBE (ALT+F11) and in the Project Explorer `View Code` for the Sheet that you have the downloaded data. Add a `Worksheet_Change` event through drop-downs above where you enter the code and put `ActiveSheet.Calculate` in the sub. See if that helps and let me know

Comment: Jerry.. Thanks for the response. xls document has the option set already, even then the problem I reported is existing. Thanks again.

Comment: mehow- I am not clear about doing things on project explorer. Sorry! My application was written in Java/Hibernate. Its not a VB application.

Comment: mehow - I got it what you are talking about. Made the changes and will update you about whether it is working or not. Thanks alot.

Comment: Finally I think I am done with this issue. I placed code like -- Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.CalculateFull
End Sub
in ThisWorkbook (by pressing alt+F11 on the xls document). Thanks mehow for helping to think in that direction.